# iOS 15 - UITableViewCell accessoryView Frame issue

Tags: ios15, accessoryview

I have a custom UIView containing UILabel as `cell.accessoryView = containerView`. It was working fine until iOS 14 but as of iOS 15, the `containerView`  is changing its frame on `tableView reload`. It is displaying properly on the first load but reloading causes the `accessoryView` to change its frame. My code is

```
        let notificationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.addSubview(notificationLabel!)
        
        cell.accessoryView = containerView
```

I am changing the frame of the container based on text in UILabel in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

It seems the frame code for `containerView` is messing up. But this is working fine in iOS 14.

I guess there are some changes and the `accessoryView` position is allowed to be changed in iOS 15.

Any suggestions to make it work without giving exact x-axis or y-axis in iOS 15?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible what your seeing is the extra "by default" padding added to the section header.

In your Viewdidload add

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
       [self.tableViewName setSectionHeaderTopPadding:0.0f];
     }
```

Comment: Not at all. I already have this check in place.

Comment: That did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for this either.  So I gave up on iOS 15's cell.accessoryView.

Instead, my cellForRowAtIndexPath handler calls:

```
[cell.contentView removeAllSubviews]
[cell.contentView addSubView:myCustomView]
```

Comment: I am still using cell.accessoryView but I am setting its frame (origin + size) properly, which is working good for iOS 15 and previous.